# Agregar numero al final de otro numero sin sumar - JAVA

Tags: java

Debo hacer un método que permita agregar un número a el final de otro número sin sumarlo.

Por ejemplo tengo 15253 y  99, debo agregar ese 99 al final del 15253, sin sumarlo, es decir que deberia resultar 1525399.

Comment: Vale la pena que leas algún tutorial sencillo de Java. Digo si le quieres sacar provecho. El método concat de la clase java.lang.String hace lo que estás buscando. Esa clase también puede convertir de números a texto y vice versa.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio .Lucas, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: @Jorge, también es importante utilizar éste tipo de "sugerencias" cuando realmente son necesarias en lugar de hacerlo "siempre" y "excesivamente" de forma recurrente para obtener "más puntos de reputación", como veo desde que empecé aquí.

Comment: @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga **no puedo obtener puntos de reputación por realizar comentarios**. Te sugiero revises lo relacionado a los comentarios y hasta que cantidad de reputación se puede obtener, además **ayuda a usuarios noveles a realizar una buena pregunta/respuesta**. En este caso es un usuario que acaba de ingresar al sitio.

Comment: ¿Lo dices tu que hace una semana le dijiste a un usuario con reputación 1 que debería poner su respuesta en un comentario? ¿Y que has editado a pregunta para cambiar el estilo usado y alguna falta de ortografía?. Dejas muy claro que no buscas obtener puntos y medallas.

Comment: @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga Si la respuesta no cumple con : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/ es obvio que se tiene que sugerir, **no somos un foro**, me parece que no has leído, y **te recomiendo revisar [ask] y [answer]**. Si deseas revisar puntualmente lo que comentas indicame que "respuesta" le sugerí agregar como comentario y en realidad era "respuesta" valida.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes concatenar ambos valores si son de tipo String por lo tanto primeramente tienes que convertirlos a este tipo.

```
int valor = 15253; 
int resultado = 99;
String cadenaResultante = String.valueOf(15253) +   String.valueOf(99);
```

aquí obtendrías una cadena que contiene "1525399", ahora si deseas convertir este valor a numérico usa el método [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), de esta forma:

```
int numeroFinal = Integer.parseInt(cadenaResultante);
```

para obtener un valor entero `1525399`

---

Si deseas un método con lo anterior se realizaría de esta forma:

```
private int concatenarNumeros(int valor, int resultado){
   String cadenaResultante = String.valueOf(valor) +   String.valueOf(resultado);
   return  Integer.parseInt(cadenaResultante); 
}
```

puedes llamar el método de esta forma:

```
int valor = concatenarNumeros(15253, 99);
```

---

#### Obviamente el valor String a convertir a entero no debe exceder de los valores: `2147483647` o `-2147483647`

Comment: truena con esto: 
    System.out.println(concatenarNumeros(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)); O sea, si la cadena resultante es mayor a un entero, truena, porque no la puede parsear.

Comment: Mi respuesta es basada en los datos que proporciona el usuario que inicia en desarrollo, en realidad sabemos que eso puede suceder si el numero excede a un entero, saludos,.

Comment: tienes razón. Quizás la pregunta está incompleta. Supongo que tus credenciales me hicieron tomar un decisión precipitada. Disculpa.

Comment: Agregué una aclaración con respecto a este tema en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer así de manera sencilla.

```
String valorStr = "";
int valor = 15253; 
int resultado = 99;

valorStr = valor + "" + resultado;  // "1525399"

valor = Integer.parseInt(valorStr); // 1525399
```